# Java "break" seems to be breaking both nested for loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

This code reads in each line from a plain text file (each line has a "list" of arrays of integers) and basically breaks it down into single integers, which are stored in a temporary array. Each line of the document must be arranged into a 2 dimensional array with an equal number of rows and columns.

The line of code that tests a condition using an "if" statement is supposed to break ONLY the inner for loop, and go back to the outer one, increment i, and move on to the next array in that line.

So far, the code I have will take only the FIRST array in each line, place it into the FIRST row of a 2D array, but will skip all the other arrays in the line and move on to the next line, where it does the same thing. So the inner loops goes once, but the outer loop never increments. Every post I've read says that "break" in a nested for loop only exits the inner loop. That doesn't seem to be the case in this situation.

So how could I make sure that the outer loop increments and all the arrays in the line are accounted for?

```
if (!thisLine.equals("*")) {
                String [] firstSplit = thisLine.split(" ");
                String [] secondSplit = new String [firstSplit.length * firstSplit.length];
                int [][] numbers = new int [firstSplit.length][firstSplit.length];
                int value = 0;
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
                    firstSplit[i] = firstSplit[i].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    secondSplit = firstSplit[i].split(",");
                    for (int j = 0; j < secondSplit.length; j++) {
                        value = Integer.parseInt(secondSplit[j]);
                        if (count >= firstSplit.length) {
                            break;
                        }
                        numbers[i][count] = value;
                        count++;
                        System.out.println(value);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(numbers));
            }
```

For example: there is a line in the file that reads: 
[6,10,15,13] [16,2,14,7] [11,8,9,3] [5,4,1,12]

'firstSplit' would break up the line by whitespace, making an array of length 4.
Then the brackets would be removed.
For each item in firstSplit, secondSplit would break it up by commas, making an array of length 16 (of individual integers).
Each item in secondSplit would be converted to an integer and placed in an array like so: 
6 at [0][0], 10 at [0][1], 15 at [0][2], 13 at [0][3].

The next array [16, 2, 14, 7] is completely ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You never reset `count`, so once it becomes higher than `firstSplit.length`, every repetition after that will `break` immediately.

You should move the initialization of `count` inside the outermost `for` loop, so that it gets reset to `0` after each time through the inner loop.

That should fix the problem you're seeing, but there's a few other things in there which I think could be improved. Your initial declaration of `secondSplit` is unnecessary, since you always assign it a new value (`firstSplit[i].split(",")`) before you use it. I'd suggest deleting that declaration, and changing the line inside the outer loop to this: `String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[i].split(",");`. That will avoid needlessly allocating a chunk of memory.

Second, unless I'm not understanding your goal, you're going to encounter problems when the array width is different from it's height. You only need `count` because you initialize `numbers[i]`'s length to be `firstSplit.length`, rather than the actual size it needs to be. I'd change your code to this:

```
String [] firstSplit = thisLine.split(" ");
int [][] numbers = new int [firstSplit.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
    firstSplit[i] = firstSplit[i].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[i].split(",");
    numbers[i] = new int[secondSplit.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < secondSplit.length; j++) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(secondSplit[j]);
        numbers[i][j] = value;
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Now it's only declaring the variables where they're actually needed, and setting the inner arrays to be the size they need.

Comment: That's a nice catch :)

Comment: That was a very simple solution that I would not have found! I'm new to java as it is. Thank you.

Comment: @galaxyphoenix67 Glad it helped. I've added some more to the post with suggestions to make your code cleaner and less likely to break (assuming I'm correctly understanding your intent. If not then ignore it all :D).

Comment: @resueman Thank you! You're right; it would completely break if the array was not a "square". I am 100% sure it will be in this situation, as that's what my text file is filled with, but it would obviously better if it could adapt to different sizes. (I think the programming term is "reusable code"; correct me if I'm wrong :P )